# Find all broken foreign key and m2m relationships in a Django app?

Tags: django, database

I've got a sqlite data dump for a django app where some models have been redacted.

How can I find all the models that have broken FK and M2M relationships* in the app ?

*I'm happy I can generate placeholder data for everything that is missing - this is so I can write a script to make sure I'm not missing some field.

Comment: By "SQLite data dump", you mean you have a `.sqlite` file in hand, or...?

Comment: I have `.sqlite` file on hand, but it's been through a process that removed some tables and renamed others.    For the removed tables, it's fine I can re-run migrations and re-populate.   What I want to do is verify my process by making sure I haven't left any broken relationships.